# Exception not caught: [vim-hug-neovim-rpc] requires one of `:pythonx import [pynvim|neovim]` command to work Deoplete Vim

Tags: vim

I'm using regular vim (not neovim) on linux. I'm trying to use Deoplete for autocomplete. I know that the title of the repository says `.nvim` at the end, but somehow the auto correct still works. But even if it works, whenever I start up vim I get this error:

```
[vim-hug-neovim-rpc] Vim(pythonx):Traceback (most recent call last):
Error detected while processing function deoplete#enable[9]..deoplete#initialize[1]..deoplete#init#_initialize[10]..<SNR>68_init_internal_variables[28]..neovim_rpc#serveraddr:
line   18:
E605: Exception not caught: [vim-hug-neovim-rpc] requires one of `:pythonx import [pynvim|neovim]` command to work
```

I don't know why it's doing this, as the auto-complete works great, but it's kind of annoying and I want to get rid of it. What can I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This solution worked for me, but I'm currently using macOS. I'm sharing because the idea behind should be the same and perhaps could help other users.

Basically, what I did was identify which Python version my VIM was using through this command inside de VIM:

```
:pythonx import sys; print(sys.path)
```

In my case I got this:

```
['/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9', '/usr/local/o
pt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '_vi
m_path_']
```

So I have to install `pynvim` using Python 3.9 and the problem was solved.

Again, in my scenario using macOS, the steps were:

```
brew link --overwrite python@3.9 --force
pip3 install pynvim
```

References:

https://github.com/roxma/vim-hug-neovim-rpc/issues/47#issuecomment-630323947
https://github.com/roxma/vim-hug-neovim-rpc/issues/47#issuecomment-622954462

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't use deoplete anymore, but I'm sure others will find this helpful.

Comment: A detail to point out; The important thing is to (re-)install pynvim/neovim for the python version used by vim. If not wishing to mess with the system's python setup, running `pythonX.YZ -m pip install --user neovim` seems to work just as well. Maybe installing the _python3-pynvim_ package is sufficient if on Debian systems. I got deoplete to resume working after those two actions.

Comment: I can confirm that on Debian 11, installing python3-pynvim is indeed sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

I stood in a front of a similar problem, but in the macOS. The only exception was, I am using many different versions of python and I preferred using python from the `pyenv` instead of the one from the brew package manager)

> **Important note**: the main disadvantage of this approach is that as a vim user (having `vim` installed via `brew` PM) every time you will update brew packages and the vim maintainers will update the dependency version of python, you will be forced to repeat this operation. The good news is, that it is not happening so often.

1. Preflight check

   ```
   $ which python
   /Users/myusername/.pyenv/shims/python

   $ python --version
   Python 3.9.7.
   ```
2. Open Vim and check which version of Python is used by the editor

   ```
   :pythonx import sys; print(sys.path)
   ```

   You should get something similar to the results below:

   ```sh
   [
      '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python310.zip',
      '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10', 
      '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
      '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages', 
      '_vim_path_', 
      '/Users/myusername/.dotfiles/configuration/.vim/plugged/vim-virtualenv/autoload'
   ]
   ```
3. Enter the directory of the python version used by the brew's vim installer, and install a missing package via its `pip3` executable

   ```sh
   /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.2/bin/pip3 install pynvim
   ```
4. Reopen vim and enjoy the absence of errors